# Получение javax.sql.DataSource через JNDI

Tags: spring

Помогите понять, как получить такой вид соединения и как это происходит.

Видел в spring.xml, но что и как понять не могу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java Naming and Directory Interface (JNDI) - это API для доступа к службам имен и каталогов. Службой имен, в самом широком смысле, называют систему, управляющую отображением множества имен во множество объектов. Зная имя объекта в системе, клиент может получить доступ к этому объекту. Примером является DNS, служба доменных имен. В ее ведении находится соответствие между понятными человеку доменными именами и понятными компьютеру сетевыми IP-адресами. Посылая DNS доменное имя, клиент получает соответствующий ему IP-адрес.

В службе каталогов поименованные объекты сгруппированы в древовидную структуру.

JNDI предназначен для единообразного доступа к разнообразным службам имен и каталогов, включая упомянутый выше DNS и файловую систему, а также LDAP. Разные службы каталогов интегрируются с JNDI через интерфейс поставщика услуг (Service Provider Interface, SPI).

Типичный пример - подключение к источнику данных (data source). Следующий код, включенный в EJB, позволяет подключиться к источнику данных, привязанному к имени "java:/DefaultDS". Этот источник данных существует в сервере приложений JBoss по умолчанию. Разумеется, можно настроить собственный источник данных и извлечь его из службы имен совершенно аналогично.

```
InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
DataSource ds = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("java:/DefaultDS");
```

Работа с JNDI всегда начинается с создания объекта `InitialContext`. Конструктор этого объекта может принимать параметры, определяющие, к какой службе и каким образом подключаться. В данном случае параметры в конструктор не передаются, поэтому происходит подключение к службе имен сервера JBoss, в котором запущен данный EJB. Затем вызов метода `lookup()` извлекает из службы имен объект, соответствующий имени "java:/DefaultDS".

Спецификация EJB 3.0 еще более упростила задачу получения объектов из службы имен. Теперь для получения того же источника данных достаточно завести член класса EJB со специальной аннотацией, а об извлечении объекта из службы имен и присвоении его члену класса позаботится EJB-контейнер.

```
@Resource(mappedName="java:/DefaultDS")
private DataSource ds;
```

Текст [отсюда](https://www.intuit.ru/studies/courses/571/427/lecture/9709) (7-й результат в Google по запросу "JNDI").