# Объясните что такое JNDI подробно

Tags: java, java-ee

Что такое JNDI? Как я понял это api для получения EJB бинов, т.е. на сервере они есть и с помощью JNDI мы получаем бин в совём приложении по его имен, я правильно понял?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Получение javax.sql.DataSource через JNDI](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/824030/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-javax-sql-datasource-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-jndi)